# Getting Runtime Exception when using generateKeyPair from SunEC provider

Tags: java, java-8, cryptography, provider, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to generate an ECC key pair by using the SunEC provider from the JDK.

Here's my code :

```
String name = paceInfo.getDomainName();

KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
try {
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    LOG.error("Unsupported Algorithm for KeyPairGenerator : EC - Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    return;
}

ECGenParameterSpec ecps = new ECGenParameterSpec(name);
try {
    kpg.initialize(ecps);
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    LOG.error("KeyPairGenerator initialization failed. ECGenParameterSpec : " + ecps.getName() + " - Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    return;
}

KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

The `paceInfo.getDomainName()` returns a String that contains the name of the specified curve I want to use. In this case, "brainpoolP256r1".

I checked that the SunEC provider is chosen when `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC")` is called and that the specified curve is supported by the provider.

When I run this code, I get the following error :

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(Native Method)
at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:128)
```

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this code. 
I'm using Java 8 (JDK 8u192) and Eclipse 2018-09.

Is there anything I do wrong ? If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is that String name = paceInfo.getDomainName(); what is the value of this String ?

Comment: @Sambit `The paceInfo.getDomainName() returns a String that contains the name of the specified curve I want to use. In this case, "brainpoolP256r1".` he clearly wrote it. Have you even read his question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ticket on Oracle bugs site](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-7007966) support for Brainpool curves was added/fixed for SunEC in Java 11, so it is available for Java 11+.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't find this ticket through my research. It explains why it is not working then.

Comment: Have just tested it with Java 11 and it works, for Java 8 it does not.

Comment: You can always use BouncyCastle library as the crypto provider which probably has support for brainpool curves.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to go with BouncyCastle. I was trying to avoid it but it seems that I can't. Thank you for your help.

Comment: FWIW, BouncyCastle supports BrainpoolP256r1